# How to compare given set with available sets to find the one with most intersecting elements, when there are a million fields in total?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-matching, system-design

Available sets are

```
A={"one","two","three"}
B={"two","three","four"}
c={"four","five"}
```

Given set is

```
D = {"four","five","six"}
```

The task is to find which available set has most intersecting elements to given set.

Here
 C contains 2 fields of D
 B contains 1 field of D.
This can be computed by finding the union of D with A, B, C.

How to find the most close-set when there are millions of available sets.

Comment: how many unique elements are there in your dataset?

Comment: A million fields approximately

Comment: you mean millions of sets and a million unique elements like "one", "two", "three", etc?

Comment: Am working on such thing
where set names are Items(mechanical components) and fields are characterstics of Items

Comment: @KannappanSirchabesan
yes you are right.

Comment: You could reverse the dictionary with the characteristics as the key and the mechanical components as the value and then perform the intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a data structure in such a way that the elements become the key. In your example, the data structure can be built to look like the below

```
"one": {A}
"two": {A,B}
"three": {A,B}
"four": {B,C}
"five": {C}
```

Now all you need to check is to take each element in your input set D and add a counter to each of the set names. so in your example, D will be {"four","five","six"}

Now you can loop through "four", "five" and "six"

```
Step 1: The counter will be all zeros initially  

Step 2: After looking at the values for "four" the counter will look like below  
B:1, C:1  

Step 3: After looking at the values for "five" the counter will look like below  
B:1, C:2  

Step 4: After looking at the values for "six" the counter will look like below   
B:1, C:2  

Step 5: Choose the set with the maximum value. In this case it will be C.
```

If you are using python, you can use collections.Counter most_common method.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter